I have bugs in Voice recognition using tflight model in python using django
import os
import numpy as np
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import tensorflow as tf
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
import logging

# 모델 파일 경로 설정
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def initialize_interpreter():
    interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(r"C:\Users\Yaggo\OneDrive\Desktop\py\django\advan\audio_project\model.tflite")
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()
    input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
    output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
    return interpreter, input_details, output_details

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'audio_app/audio_recorder.html')

@csrf_exempt
def upload_audio(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES.get('audio_data'):
            audio_file = request.FILES['audio_data']
            audio_data = np.frombuffer(audio_file.read(), dtype=np.int16)

            # 데이터 길이가 int16의 크기로 나누어 떨어지는지 확인
            if len(audio_data) % 2 != 0:
                audio_data = audio_data[:-1]  # 마지막 바이트 제거

            # 데이터 정규화 및 모델 입력 크기 조정
            audio_data = audio_data.astype(np.float32) / 16384.0  #32768.0
            interpreter, input_details, output_details = initialize_interpreter()
            print(f"Model input shape: {input_details[0]['shape']}")
            if audio_data.size < input_details[0]['shape'][1]:
                audio_data = np.pad(audio_data, (0, input_details[0]['shape'][1] - audio_data.size), 'constant')
            elif audio_data.size > input_details[0]['shape'][1]:
                audio_data = audio_data[:input_details[0]['shape'][1]]
            audio_data = np.reshape(audio_data, input_details[0]['shape'])

            # TensorFlow Lite 모델 실행
            interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], audio_data)
            interpreter.invoke()

            # 예측 결과 가져오기
            output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])[0]
            print("Model output:", output_data)
            logger.debug(f"Model output: {output_data}")
            return JsonResponse({
                'audio_data': audio_data.tolist(),  # audio_data 값을 반환
                'predicted_indices': output_data.tolist()  # JSON 직렬화 가능한 형태로 변환
            })
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'No audio file provided'}, status=400)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('Error processing audio file: %s', str(e))
        return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, status=500)


this is view.py and
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const recordButton = document.getElementById('recordButton');
    const statusElement = document.getElementById('status');
    const audioDataElement = document.getElementById('audioData');

    recordButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        let isRecording = false;

        function startRecording() {
            if (isRecording) return;

            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
                .then(stream => {
                    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
                    let audioChunks = [];

                    mediaRecorder.start();
                    isRecording = true;
                    statusElement.textContent = "Recording for 5 seconds...";

                    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
                        audioChunks.push(event.data);
                    });

                    setTimeout(() => {
                        mediaRecorder.stop();
                        stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
                    }, 5000);

                    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
                        let audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks);
                        sendDataToServer(audioBlob);
                        audioChunks = [];
                        isRecording = false;
                    });
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.error("Error accessing media devices.", error);
                    statusElement.textContent = "Error: Audio permission is required.";
                });
        }

        startRecording();

        setInterval(() => {
            if (!isRecording) {
                startRecording();
            }
        }, 8000);
    });

    function sendDataToServer(audioBlob) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("audio_data", audioBlob);
        fetch("/audio/upload-audio/", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`Server responded with a status: ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            if (audioDataElement) {
                audioDataElement.textContent = "Model Output: " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + " - " + data.predicted_indices.join(', ');
            } else {
                console.error("audioData element not found");
                statusElement.textContent = "Error: audioData element not found";
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error handling response: ", error);
            statusElement.textContent = "Error: " + error.message;
        });
    }
});

this is record.js
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import upload_audio
urlpatterns = [
    path('upload-audio/', upload_audio, name='upload_audio'),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),  
]

this is app/urls.py
from django.urls import path, include
from audio_app.views import home  # views를 임포트하는 부분이 추가되어야 합니다.
from audio_app.views import upload_audio
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),  # 홈 페이지 URL
    path('audio/upload-audio/', upload_audio, name='upload_audio'),
]


lastly,this project/urls.py
i have two problem
ERROR:audio_app.views:Error processing audio file: buffer size must be a multiple of element size
Internal Server Error: /audio/upload-audio/
ERROR:django.request:Internal Server Error: /audio/upload-audio/
and the model output doesn`t work
it should out like[0.xxxx,0.xxxx,0.xxxx] but only out[0,1,0]
can you guys help the young and inspired student....
nevermind about korean commentary
i tried to add logcontainer but it make a lot of bugs i dont why
and i tried a lot of questions for gpt4 and 4o and coding code but they repeat what they saying that doesnt work

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
